# Why does it matter how many taxpayers' dollars I have spent?

Tags: puzzle-agent

When you finish a puzzle, you get a number of taxpayers' dollars spent. It is always a pretty large number, and it doesn't seem to have a point.

What is the purpose of the number? Is it my score or something?

Comment: Its just a joke, implying that a ludicrous amount of taxpayer money is being paid to a government agent in order to get erasers for the president.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has no bearing on the game proper, but it seems to be related to how many attempts it took you to finish a puzzle.  It's more something you can use to compare against friends, and not something that has any meaning aside from that (that I noticed).